# Importing xlsx into R, header contains dates that are converted

Tags: r

I imported data into R, but the column headers in the xlsx file, contain Date types, see sample here:

```
GrowthValue 15-May  15-Jun   15-Jul  15-Aug  15-Sep  15-Oct
```

So in the table header of the spreadsheet `15-May` gets translated to the variable name `X42505` in R.

I could not find anything in my searches. How do you preserve the Date in the header?

Comment: How did you import your data?

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't like numbers as column names, so it adds X as a prefix.
You should avoid column names that start with numbers, but if that's what you want, here is a solution ([source](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/40315-quot-X-quot-in-front-of-my-column-names-I-want-it-to-stop!!)):

```
read.table(file, check.names=FALSE)
```

If you want to reference these columns, you quote them.

```
df$'15-May'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. So based on your source, I can put check.names=FALSE as a parameter to read.xlsx. If this fixes the issue this is great that this scenario is handled.

Comment: "R doesn't like numbers" isn't quite correct; what's more accurate is "R doesn't like numbers as col.names". Adding the X is an automatic failsafe, and whatever you do with a df that has numeric-started col.names will look weird.

Comment: HI, I just tried check.names=FALSE this as a parameter and it only removed the the X but left the number part: 42505. So I guess we are getting closer. SO would there be another parameter that handles Dates in particular, I know you guys are saying its  because the columns don't like numbers in the beginning, but is there a way to cast it to string?

Comment: I changed the date to May-2016, so the letter parts first and the number last, but I still get the date as a number in Rstudio's column header.

Comment: @AndrewCheesman whoops, that's a big typo.  I edited it to match your correction.  Thank you for that important clarification.  @Palu sample data?  You can try 'melt` on the columns and convert Excel dates to R dates.

Comment: That 42505 is Excel's native date storage format: May-15 or whatever is just display. (Note that if you change the Excel format for 42505 from Short Date to Long Date, the actual day for 42505 is May-15-2015.) So R's reading in the data correctly - it's not the case that R is transforming May-15 to X42505 or 42505. Edit: check out this link. http://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/ for converting Excel-based date numbers to Datetime in R. If you want your field headers to be reactive, then extract them and overwrite once you import the DF.

Comment: OK, thanks Oshun and Andrew. SO is this 'melt' a command in R-stats. Please let me know.

Comment: `melt` from reshape2 package.  There are other similar functions.  Search for "data from wide to long format"

Comment: Hi there, i am familiar with getting data to go from wide<->long format, but how does this help with setting the header data to a good data type for the sake of display in the table header section of RStudio.